# How to use onclick in an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I got the following code on w3school :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changetext(id)
{
id.innerHTML="Ooops!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 onclick="changetext(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working well.
Now for the sake of practice, I want want to do it by an external js file. 
My codes are as follows
Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to execute the <em>displayDate()</em> function.</p>

<button >Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file:

```
function displayDate()
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
onclick='displayDate()';
```

But above code is not working. What should I do for this.

Comment: YOu cant right like this - onclick='displayDate()'; in js file

Comment: Thanks.. What should I do for this..

Comment: CHeckout answer given by @Maurice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is often done with an ID on the button. To ensure the DOM is loaded when the script is executed, it is done in a load handler.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <p>Click the button to execute the <em>displayDate()</em> function.</p>

   <button id="myButton">Try it</button>

   <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

function.js:

```
function displayDate()
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}

window.onload = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
    btn.onclick = displayDate;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use window.onload ?

Comment: Yes it is, because if you set the handler directly in the script, the markup may be incomplete, and the button may not exist. But I just noticed the jquery tag in your question; if you're using jquery, it can be a little simpler.

Comment: I am very new to Javascript and do not know anything about jquery. Should I try it after studying jquery ? I am editing tags.

Comment: My opinion is that you should start with learning Javascript, then learn jquery.

Comment: Yes sir, I am doing the same. But for the above problem ,should I take the help of jquery?

Comment: Not necessary: just use the onload handler

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51013/discussion-between-jahan-and-maurice-perry)

Comment: It would border on insanity to include the jquery library just to accomplish this. But believe it or not,  that gets done all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to execute the <em>displayDate()</em> function.</p>

<button id="try it" onclick='displayDate()' >Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="function.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file

```
    function displayDate()
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this answer being downvoted? Is it because the click event shouldn't be in the HTML? Because the code seems to work just fine.

Comment: I can't understand why the answer is downvoted either !!
anyway I hope it helped.